# Ubuntu 16.04 Wi-Fi network disconnected

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having a problem with wifi in my ubuntu 16.04. Just suddenly after opening laptop after sleep it stopped working. I couldn't connect to wifi.

I'm helpless. I tried several things. Restarting network manager, editing interfaces etc.
Can anyone help me, please?

Here's how it looks:
[the wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy3Av.jpg)

On Edit Connections, I deleted the old ones and I created a Bridge then added ethernet  connection type but the device doesn't appear there:
[edit connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cu4M.jpg)

Here's the content of /etc/network/interfaces:
[interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbYGV.jpg)

Here's what I get from iwconfig:
[iwconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYX4E.jpg)

I have no idea how to fix this. On it can't connect to a wired cable cause it doesn't have it. I can't download anything. HELP!

EDIT:

when I type  **nmcli d** on terminal I get this: 
[nmcli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdUD8.jpg)

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: I did "sudo reboot" @DrMoishePippik

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I edited the question, added `nmcli d` results when wlp3S0  wifi is disconnected, do you have any idea?

Comment: Take a look at **/var/log/dmesg**. Also try **rfkill list all** to see if it's being hardblocked